# Problems connecting Scilab with php?

Tags: php, scilab, interfacing

I try to use/call Scilab with php. I followed instruction form https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-scilab/os-php-scilab-pdf.pdf but I cant make it work. I tried listing 1 and what I got is Array (). do I need to save sci/sce file in root folder before calling them in php? is Scilab can be called directly as the instruction?

Comment: Any code to see your start point ?

Comment: i don't have any. i directly use the code from instructions. i copy the code here. this my first time posting something here so please do correct my way of doing things. btw here is the code
 <?php
exec('scilab -nwni -nb -e "m=[1 2 3; 3 4 5];disp(m);exit;"', $output);
print_r($output);
?>

Comment: i cant post long code so here is print screen https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwzS414fFHBnX1BaR21lVUw1cG8

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I use scilab 6.0.1

This code works for me :

```
<?php
$path = 'C:\\wamp64\\apps\\scilab-6.0.1\\bin\\';
$path_script = 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\tests\\log.sce';
$command = $path.'WScilex-cli.exe -nb -f '.$path_script;

echo $command;
exec($command, $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($output);
echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

In the log.sce file, I saw matrix on firefox web page, save file and picture on my folder.

Best regards